# How to search for underscores to select file duplicates, whilst leaving out original files that may have underscores in them?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, file-search

I have a bunch of files that have duplicated, with an "_1", "_2" etc added to the end. I know I can do a search to show everything with _1, but there are some files that also have _1 in the filename, about halfway through. Such a search would also bring up those orignal files, and I only want to delete the duplicates. Any ideas on how I can do this?

- 20230528_134316
- 20230528_134316_1
- 20230528_134316_2

In this case, searching for _1 will also bring up the original file. How can I only select the duplicates? Maybe only searching the last couple digits in the filename? Maybe I can only show results where the _1 is the very end of the filename? I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: While not exactly what you intended something like dupeGuru https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/ a free opensource program can search folders for duplicate files, and allows you to select all the duplicates and do something like delete them or move them. Though it won't always pick the shorter filename as the one to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following syntax to find `_1` at the end of the file-name :

```
"*_1"
```

The quotes cause the search to be on the entire name,
not for a sub-string.

For file-names that have an extension, you could use :

```
"*_1.*"
```

For more information see the article
[Advanced Query Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: This mostly works for me, but for some reason doesn't work with .mp4 files. Any idea why that might be? When I do the search in a folder that only has mp4s, nothing shows up in the results. Could it be that maybe those files all had their file extension as part of the filename?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on epub files either.

Comment: Can you add to your post some examples of mp4/epub file-names.

Comment: Here is an epub example: A New Beginning-1_1.epub

Comment: I added the case of an extension to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your filenames seem to have a set format, you could search for files that have

```
*_??????_*.*
```

as the pattern. This will search for files with two underscore characters in the file name, separated by any 6 characters.

- asterisk (*) finds any length of any characers (including no characters)
- question mark (?) finds any single character.
- the full stop (.) separates the file name from the file extension.

Depending on the files you may also be able to use `*_*_*.*` to find any file with two underscores in the filename with any pattern.

Comment: While this is a good answer, There was actually a lot of different naming conventions used across the files, so I needed more of a one size fits all approach.